# How to display multiple contents without reloading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing some webpage which based on `html5`. On my page I want to have some `nav` and container with selected content. But I don't want reload page after click on menu position.

**At first** I thought about placed whole content on site, hide some of them and show after click.

[very simple example of this](http://jsfiddle.net/4YCrm/)

But there are a lot of content which is hidden and I'm not sure is this a good idea.

**Then** I think about include a content from `.html` files by javascript and placed them on site, but my little research tells me this is very bad practice. [Some article.](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html)

**Also** this is small, and simple page and I don't want to use any backend technologies.

So, my **question** is: What is the best practise for doing this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I use .html on my website so I dont have to reload the data, every time it just corresponds with .ajax in jquery both a really useful

Comment: Iframes may help here. Not always hiding and showing div's, just loading into a container.

Comment: You may want to check out jQuery's [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function. It is specifically designed to call the server and fetch additional html that can be appended to the element you specify.

Comment: @tymeJV Just a side note. Iframes could definitely work it. Be aware though that they prevent the user from deep linking and bookmarking. Also, it makes it difficult for search engine crawlers to properly index your site. Just a heads up.

Comment: your article is pretty much outdated so don't mind about it! It says and I quote : "but the browser has to be IE5 and more" since we're now at IE10, well...!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but with the first option of placing the whole content on site then show / hiding it, you have a lot of unnecessary overhead, especially if they don't visit those other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the *best way* is but I recommend using [jQuery's `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) along with [jQuery's `.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).

First, use `.ajaxSetup()` so you can cache future ajax requests.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true
});
```

Then, bind a `.click()` event that uses `.load()`.

Here is the code from my example...

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="first">first</li>
    <li id="second">second</li>
    <li id="last">last</li>
</ul>
<ul id="contents">
    <li id="content1">first</li>
    <li id="content2">second</li>
    <li id="content3">last</li>
</ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: true
    });

    $('#nav>li').click(function(){
       var url = 7;
       index = $(this).index();
        url += index;
       $('#content' + (index + 1)).load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/dirtyd77/jUEEd/' + url + '/show/');
    });   
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/jUEEd/13/

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: To add to this you probably want to add some hashtag change or similar (pushState) so you can link + forward / back through content.